# Redirecting back to cached version of App ( IE 11 - DOM7011 ) - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer, material-ui

I am experiencing a strange behaviour from IE11 . 
It seems like Chrome can handle a lot of things on its own and it works fine , but when i wrap my `Material UI` component `<Input />` into an HTML `<form>` IE is redirecting me back to an cached version of the app with an console error :
`DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching.`

Here is an example :

```
  return (
    <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <Input id="standard-basic" label="Standard" />
      <Button type='submit' onClick={handleClick()} color='primary' variant='contained'>Click</Button>
    </form>
  );
```

Comment: Try TextField instead of Input

Comment: @owaislatif i have the same result

Comment: can you please try simple html input field

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem on my side, I have tested the [Material-UI Inputs](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#inputs) sample, it seems that everything work well on my side. As owais latif said, you could try to use html input field, or try to change the `<form>` tag to `<div>` tag. If still not working, I suggest you could try to create a [Stackblitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/) to reproduce the problem.